# Run multiple commands through SSH inside docker container from C#

Tags: c#, docker, ssh, freeradius

I need to run multiple commands in docker container through SSH from C#. I am using Renci.sshnet for ssh connection. Here is my code:

```
  {
      ssh.Connect();
      var command = ssh.CreateCommand("sudo docker exec - it freeradius bash &&"+" echo User-Name=" + username + ",Framed-IP-Address=" + framedipaddress + "| radclient -x " + nasipaddress + ":1700 disconnect a1rp0c9ptio8");
      strReturn = command.Execute().ToString();
  }
```

if manually i am doing , these two lines commands working fine for me. but from ssh not working...any idea please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your complete command in bash parameter `-c`:

```
$ docker exec -it sad_kilby bash -c "echo 123 && echo $? && ls / | grep etc"
123
0
etc
```

So your command will be like this:

```
string subcommand = "echo User-Name=" + username + ",Framed-IP-Address=" + framedipaddress + "| radclient -x " + nasipaddress + ":1700 disconnect a1rp0c9ptio8"
var command = ssh.CreateCommand("sudo docker exec -it freeradius bash -c \"" + subcommand + "\"")
```

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to mark this answer as solution:)